# Traversing through the inode to find the contents of the file stored in different data blocks

Tags: inode, superblock

I am reading about the EXT2 filesystem and I got an understanding about it. Every file system comprises of data and metadata (inode). The file system is divided into a number of blocks with 4 main blocks containing information about other blocks.

How the interaction happens if we try to open a file from the user space ?

When the user calls the `open()` syscall, how is the file located through the inode number and how are the contents stored in the next block identified?

`open()` calls `sys_open()` which in turn calls the `do_path_search()` function by looking for the inode number with the filename. It obtains the inode number that holds the data blocks address by looking at the table of the inode numbers.

- How does it search the remaining contiguous block?
- How does it identify which filesystem has to searched to get the correct file?
- How is the file structure maintained by multiple processes accessing the same file?

Comment: This is an awful lot of questions. How about you think about each one separately, and ask them separately.

Comment: I have shortened the question